# Powershell script to create text files in all the drives

Tags: windows, powershell

I am new to PowerShell and looking for some help. Here I am trying to create a text file in all the drives but seems I am missing something here, any help is appreciated:

```
$drives = get-psdrive -p "FileSystem"
foreach ($drive in $drives)
{
New-Item -Path '$drive:\IO.txt' -ItemType File
}
```

Also, have another query regarding the same that how I can exclude particular drives e.g. "A:", "C:", "D:" drives?

Thanks

Comment: Using the single quotations means that `'$drive'` is being read literally and not expanded to a path or collection. You would need to do `"$Drive"` to expand the full details, that should work for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more what you are after.

```
$drives = get-psdrive -p "FileSystem"
$exclude = "C","D"

foreach ($drive in $drives) {
# Exclamation (!) is the same as -not meaning if not $true > Do the thing
    If(!$exclude.Contains($drive.Name)) { 
        New-Item -Path "$($drive):\IO.txt" -ItemType File
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, this worked perfectly fine like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Give `New-Item -ItemType File -Name "Filename.ext"` a shot,

see: https://mathieubuisson.github.io/powershell-linux-bash/

Comment: Thanks bgsuello, shared link is very useful atleast for newbies like me :)

Answer (score 0):

A more PowerShell like way is to filter the drives with a `Where-Object` and
do it in a single pipe

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider "FileSystem" |
  Where-Object Name -notmatch 'A|C|D' |
    New-Item -Path {"$($_.Name):\IO.txt"} -ItemType File -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK remove the trailing `-WhatIf`